# Replicate 100 times

Tags: r

I want to draw 100 random samples with size 187 from Binomial distribution for fixed probability value. I have attached here my R-code, where I got 1 random samle with size 187. But I can't store the results for 100 times. How can I store it? That means there will be 100 columns and each column there will be 187 observations.

```
mdata=read.csv("c:/germany/st_it.csv",header=TRUE)###susceptibe and infective number on a day t
t<-read.csv("c:/germany/pt_new.csv",header=TRUE)
t1=t$PRO
s=mdata$st  ## susceptible
s1=mdata$it ### infected
q=0.9946289
b=numeric(nrow(mdata))
for (i in 1:(nrow(mdata))){
  b[i]=rbinom(1,s[i],q^(s1[i]))
}
sus=numeric(187)
sus[1]=b[1]
for (j in 2:187) {
  ifelse(t1[j]==t1[j-1], sus[j]<-sus[j-1], sus[j]<-b[j])
}
sus
```

Comment: you can greatly simplify this code with `rbinom(187, s, q^s1)` - rbinom is vectorised. Use `replicate(100, rbinom(...))` to make a matrix

Comment: @RichardTelford Or `replicate(100, rbinom(187, s, q^s1))`.